# Sorting an Array from an HTML element using array.sort

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a word and number sorting program for a class final, but I can't get array.sort to work with an HTML element.

```
<textarea name="data" placeholder="Input data here:" class="inputBox" id="dataInput"></textarea>

// sorting words
//moving HTML input into array
function addDataWords() {
//clear dataOutput
  let dataWords = [];
  document.getElementById('dataOutput').innerHTML = '';
//push into array
  dataWords.push(document.getElementById('dataInput').value.split(','));
  console.log(dataWords);
//sort words
  dataWords.sort();
  console.log(dataWords);
  document.getElementById('dataOutput').innerHTML = dataWords;
}
```

Debugger shows that HTML elements are being moved into the array, but .sort doesn't seem to sort them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `split()` returns an array. You are then pushing that array into the empty `dataWords` array as a sub array. So it would look like:

`[['word1','word2'...]]`

But you want `['word1','word2'...]`

Just do :

```
let dataWords = document.getElementById('dataInput').value.split(',');
```

```js
function addDataWords() { 
 
  // split comma delimited values into an array
  let dataWords =document.getElementById('dataInput').value.split(',');
  
  //sort words
  dataWords.sort();
  console.log(dataWords);
  document.getElementById('dataOutput').innerHTML = dataWords.join(', ');
}

addDataWords()
```

```html
<textarea name="data" id="dataInput">foo,bar,two,one</textarea>

<div id="dataOutput"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function `.split()` returns a new array.
So the output of your function is something like:

```
[['B', 'C', 'B']] // Example
```

So in this situation the easy solution is that you should sort the nested array

```
dataWords[0].sort();
```

Or a better way will be:

```
function addDataWords() {
  const dataWords = [];
  document.getElementById('dataOutput').innerHTML = '';

  const dataInput = document.getElementById('dataInput').value.split(','));
  for (let data of dataInput) {
     dataWords.push(data);
  }

  console.log(dataWords);
  document.getElementById('dataOutput').innerHTML = dataWords;
}
```

Comment: *"returns a new array"* .. again, no it doesn't

Comment: It does! if not then what is the array inside dataWords[] array?

Comment: Not the sort(), but the split()

Comment: That is not the correct way to compare arrays in Javascript

Comment: I was comparing the objects. If the original statement was accurate they would not have been same object reference.

Comment: @charlietfl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: You are conflating two completely different issues

Comment: Anyways, it was a good discussion and thank you! Discussions make us learn something new and I liked the way you tried to correct me.